# Missing required parameter error on route with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel-5

this error message keep showing

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: merchants.add.channel] [URI: merchants/{key}/denomination/{keydenom}/channel/addChannel].
```

here is my route

```
Route::get('merchants/{key}/denomination/{keydenom}/channel', 'MerchantsController@channel')->name('merchants.channel');
```

here is my function

```
public function channel($id)
{
  if (!can('merchants_list_channel')) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
  }
  $merchant = MerchantDenomination::where('id', $id)->pluck('name')->first();
  $statusDenomList = [
      '' => '-- All --',
      'ACTIVE' => 'Active',
      'DISABLE' => 'Disable',
      'OFS' => 'OFS'
  ];
    return view('merchants.channel', compact('statusDenomList', 'id', 'merchant'));
}
```

Comment: Your method expects a parameter for `$id` but you're not passing one?

Answer (score 0):

The route has 2 route parameters: {key} and {keydenom}.

Your controller function should expect both of them:

```
public function channel($key, $keydom) {
  // Do your job
}
```

You also need to express the params everytime you call `route()`:

```
 route('merchants.channel', ['key' => "your-key", 'keydom' => "your-keydom"])
```